Can init code of a contract not return the deployed code?
As I understand, when deploying a new smart contract, the transaction has only the init code, which includes the code that will be actually deployed (the deployed code). The init code is executed and then it should return the deployed code that will be the code of the smart contract on the blockchain.
So my question is, what if the init code does not return or return nothing, will the transaction be reverted and smart contract not created? If it's not reverted, can we just use this to run code without creating contracts?
P.S. Just found out about the create opcode. Is this opcode used when creating a contract? So what if my init code never uses it?

The transactions that creates a contract will always end in a return or revert, so you always deploy something or revert.

If it's not reverted, can we just use this to run code without creating contracts?

You can end the constructor with selfdestruct if you don't want to leave a contract behind. Or you can end it with assembly { return(0,0) }, basically leaving empty bytecode.

P.S. Just found out about the create opcode. Is this opcode used when creating a contract? So what if my init code never uses it?

create is one method of deploying contracts. Only other contracts can use it, not EOA (normal wallets). You can use the create opcode in your constructor if you want to deploy an extra contract in the same transaction. So, no, it's not needed normally.
Hopefully I've cleared some doubts.
